# How can i use a free AWS account like Azure provides?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create or use an AWS account to verify a few things as to whether it will meet our company needs. Azure provides a free account to use no payment required, whereas AWS doesnt seem to have that option or it is very difficult to use .

I have looked at the free tier, but i dont want to provide any details at the moment .

How can i get a free account , even if there are limits to certain services ?

Comment: The AWS Free Tier is simply a billing discount. The AWS Account you create is totally the same as a 'normal' AWS Account (because that's all there is!). The services you create and use will not be impacted in any way by the fact that you are taking advantage of the Free Tier.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Free Tier is what you're looking for.  And, yes, you must provide billing details to use it.  Any other legitimate customer would.

If you're concerned about accidentally spending a bunch of money, you can set yourself a spending limit in the billing options.

Comment: Ok , so if i get my company to sign up and create a business acct. Im assuming then i can easily create  s3 buckets and access them , thats what im mostly interested in ?  Or does the free tier not offer that?    I have seen online that some people are getting errors that s3 is having issues in us-west (oregon) region.  Will this happen if i do a full free tier Business signup ?

Comment: @Sally I don't know what S3 issues you're referring to... you can check the AWS status board for info:  https://health.aws.amazon.com/health/status  It doesn't matter what tier of account you have.  And yes, S3 has a free tier.